# GCC says "(re)declaration", Clang says "(re)definition", MSVC says both

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

Sample code:

```
void f(void)
{
    int x;
    int x;
}
```

Invocations:

```
$ gcc t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
t0.c: In function 'f':
t0.c:4:9: error: redeclaration of 'x' with no linkage
    4 |     int x;
      |         ^
t0.c:3:9: note: previous declaration of 'x' with type 'int'
    3 |     int x;
      |         ^

$ clang t0.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
t0.c:4:9: error: redefinition of 'x'
    int x;
        ^
t0.c:3:9: note: previous definition is here
    int x;
        ^

$ cl t0.c /std:c11 /Za
t0.c(4): error C2086: 'int x': redefinition
t0.c(3): note: see declaration of 'x'
```

As I understand `int x;` is a *definition* of an identifier `x`. Is that correct?

Comment: `int x;` inside a function is a definition of `x`. It is also a declaration of `x`. All the compiler phrasings shown are correct.

Comment: Every definition is also a declaration; some declarations are not definitions.  See also [What is the difference between a declaration and a definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)

Comment: See also the C11 standard [§6.7 Declarations ¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p5): _A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that: • for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;_